# Android - как достать изображение из php?

Tags: captcha, android, php, java

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь достать изображение капчи [отсюда](http://www.afreesms.com/image.php) и впихнуть его в ImageView. Прикол в том, что мне возвращается по сути php файл, а не изображение. Вопрос: как мне достать [отсюда](http://www.afreesms.com/image.php) капчу и вывести её в ImageView?

Извиняюсь за возможно неправильное название вопроса.

Comment: по ссылке выше возвращается именно картинка. Это просто привычка с винды, что расширения файла что то решает. Гуглите просто на тему "скачать картинку и показать ImageView".

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно парсить hml-документ, генерируемый php-скриптом и вытаскивать url-адрес картинки(тега img). Тогда ты сможешь ее загрузить в ImageView по этому url.

Answer (score 1):

В файле image.php находиться зашифрованная картинка в base64.  Если достать текст и расшифровать - полчите вашу капчу.
Метод для получения bitmap из base64:

```
public static Bitmap convertBase64toBitmap(String encodedImage) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}
```